# How can I optimize result video?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using the command below to mix several media into only one video file. The first one is the main media (a video or an image). The second is always a PNG image with transparent background that I need to resize to fit into main video. Finally I can have multiple gif files that I need to place over video each one in its own position (from left and top). It is working just fine!

The point is: The output video always get at least 8mb, no matter crf I try and no matter (too much) the video size in seconds. How can I reduce the output video size?

```
-i 1600261920321.mp4
-i 1600261955778.png
-ignore_loop 0 -i 1600261947800.gif
-filter_complex "
    [1:v]scale=1080:2131.1650485436894[widgets];
    [0:v]hue=h=0:s=1:b=0[mainMedia]; 
    [mainMedia][widgets]overlay[mix1]; 
    [2:v]
        rotate=0.0:ow='hypot(iw,ih)':oh=ow:c=none,
        scale=w=541.8349514563107:h=614.0221402214023
    [gif1];
    [mix1][gif1]overlay=77.60453308747434:1233.60366595435:shortest=1[outfile]
"
-map [outfile]
-map 0:a
-r 15
-c:a aac
-c:v libx265
-crf 31
-preset ultrafast
1600261955595.mp4
```

Comment: If you take the output video and re-encode it, what is the size?  In other words, have you checked to see whether this has anything at all to do with how you assemble the pictures, or is it just due to the video content itself?

Comment: Maybe try two-pass encoding to see what happens.

Comment: I'll make some tests to see what happens @tetech

Comment: @DanielB How can I do that?

Comment: @tetech tryed to compile only the main file in several ways, but nothing that I change take any effects =/

Comment: There's nothing that I do to get less than 8mb, even using methods to compress without ffmpeg. Anyone knows how this is possible?

Comment: Please edit the question to provide details about the input video - file size, resolution, encoding, duration in seconds, etc.

Comment: Show the complete log from the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved]

Thank you all. Actually there was nothing wrong with the command line or even with ffmpeg. I'm using Flutter and the only problem was a lib to save the file to the device gallery, for some reason this lib save a minimum size of 8mb to store the file and the problem was resolved only changing to another lib to do that.